# Spotlight Date calculator

Tags: macos, high-sierra, spotlight

Do you know the way (system pref., additional app etc.) to enable Date calculator inside Spotlight app?
I'm using regular calculator a lot but I would like to have there an option to add one time duration to another like: '30m + 20m' or '0:30 + 0:20' and get from spotlight 50m or 0:50.

Basically format of time doesn't matter, I'm asking about functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `30min + 30min` gave me `60 minutes`. `30 sec + 20 sec` and `30sec + 20sec` also work, giving me `50 seconds`. macOS Ventura 13.4

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a way to do it in Spotlight, but if you use Alfred app, you can add the behavior with Workflows. I found this Workflow helpful, https://github.com/LeEnno/alfred-date-calculator.

Answer (score 1):

In macOS Ventura 13.5 the following time calculation syntax works:

Entering `2h+3h20m-2h` in Spotlight returns "3 hours 20 minutes"

EDIT: For whatever reason, it appears that "m" can only be used once, e.g. `2h3m + 5h20m + 1h1m` will not work. However, "min" can be used multiple times, e.g. `2h3m + 5h20min + 1h1min`.